# 'strip --strip-all' works but 'strip --strip-symbol=symbolname' won't because it is named in a relocation

Tags: linux, module, symbols, strip

As the title states.  I can use `strip --strip-all` and it will strip all the symbols out of a .ko file.  However, if I tried to remove just one symbol with `strip --strip-symbol=symbolname` it complains by saying `strip: not stripping symbol 'symbolname' because it is named in a relocation`

How can I force it to strip the symbols. If it can't be done then can ld generate random symbol names?  Or is there a utility to change symbol names?

TIA!!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question on stripping but for renaming, the objcopy command can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My testing shows that stripping doesn't work on .ko files.  This matches what others have said during my searches for an answer.   You appear to be limited to renaming the symbols (using objcopy) if you need to suppress them.